# How to traverse circle coordinates?

Tags: computational-geometry

The problem I have is:

> Fill a circle by drawing one-pixel-wide horizontal lines across its inside area.

My initial thought is to generate the circles' coordinates symmetrically to a vertical axis passing through its centre, using the parametric equations:
\begin{align}
x &= x_{\rm offset} + r \cdot \cos\theta \\
y &= y_{\rm offset} + r \cdot \sin\theta
\end{align}

and letting the angle $\theta$ decrementing<sup>1</sup> from $270^\circ$ to $180^\circ$, to generate the starting points of the horizontal lines and then incrementing<sup>1</sup> for the $I$ and $IV$ quadrants: from $270^\circ$ to $360^\circ$ to generate the ending points of the lines.

As mathematics is clearly not my forte, I am asking the following:

### Question:

1. Should I proceed with the implementation of the above rationale or is there a more efficient<sup>2</sup> method to achieve the task?

### Note:

The coordinate system I use is left-handed: the $y$ coordinate increases downwards.

---

<sup>1. By the thickness of the lines</sup>

<sup>2. Using less calculations.</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $r_y=-r\ldots r$, let $r_x=\sqrt{r^2-r_y^2}$ and draw the line at: $y=y_{\text{offset}}+r_y$
from $x=x_{\text{offset}}-r_x$ to $x=x_{\text{offset}}+r_x$.

Answer (score 1):

Say that the circle has center $(a, b)$ and radius $r$.  Its equation is
$$
(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 = r^2.
$$
For any particular $y$, we can solve for $x$ in terms of that $y$ to find the left and right endpoints of the horizontal segment:
\begin{align}
(x-a)^2 &= r^2 - (y-b)^2 \\
\lvert x-a \rvert &= \sqrt{r^2 - (y-b)^2} \\
x-a &= \pm \sqrt{r^2 - (y-b)^2} \\
x &= a \pm \sqrt{r^2 - (y-b)^2}
\end{align}

Now, for each $y$ in the interval $[b-r, b+r]$, you have to draw the horizontal segment at height $y$ between the $x$-coordinates
$$
a - \sqrt{r^2 - (y-b)^2} 
\quad\text{and}\quad
a + \sqrt{r^2 - (y-b)^2}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

I see you already have accepted an answer... You are asking about a classical problem in computer graphics, which has been solved long time ago using only *integer* calculations.

Please see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm) for the description of the algorithm.